# IOCP or TASK communication between server-client

Tags: multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, task, iocp

I need to implement server-client communications which must keep a lot of connections (1k-3k).
What better to choose, IOCP or Task Async?

Comment: What language and platform?

Comment: C#. Wndows Platform.

Answer (score 1):

3k connections force an async design. This is true. However, this is not a very high amount of connections. As long as you do not make severe mistakes this will work reliably under pretty much any modern async IO style.

Simply use managed code and `await`.

I believe .NET uses IOCP under the covers for async IO on sockets anyway. So you get nice task-based async IO with IOCP.